# How to read and find the largest value from .csv with the use of window batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv, file-io, max

In my .csv file,

```
abc,10/24/2013,ABC
cede,5/1/2013,ABCk
cdeh,7/27/2014,ABCf
cdedsf,1/27/2014,gfABC
.
.
.(1xx more lines with similar text)
```

I would like to find the latest date in the middle field (e.g. 7/27/2014 in above case) and save to a variable named as "latest_date".

However, I do not know how to read the specific field from a .csv file and find the latest date with such format(M/D/Y).

Can anyone teach me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in (
       ' cmd /q /v:on /c "for /f "tokens^=2-4 delims^=^,/" %%a in (data.csv) do (set /a "x^=%%c*10000+%%a*100+%%b" >nul & echo(^!x:~0,4^!/^!x:~4,2^!/^!x:~-2^!)" ^| sort /r '
    ) do set "last_date=%%b/%%c/%%a" & goto done

:done
    echo %last_date%
```

How does it work?

The input file is readed via a `for /f` loop (the inner one). Each record is tokenized, using the commas and slashes as delimiters. This leaves the tokens 2 to 4 as the elements of the date. This elements are normalized (month and days have one or two digits, years are at the end) with some arithmetics to get a `yyyy/mm/dd` date, and the resulting dates are echoed. This list of dates is sorted in inversed order (so the greatest date is in the first record).

As the process in defined as a pipe (each process inside a pipe run in a separate cmd instance), and as the left part of the pipe requires delayed expansion enabled, the `for /f` that reads the file is executed inside its own instance of `cmd` with the adecuated configuration: echo off (`/q`) and delayed expansion active (`/v:on`).

The sorted list, will be readed with another `for /f` loop (the outer one), that will tokenize the retrieved data, separating again the year, month and day, so the final variable have the required format (`mm/dd/yyyy`). As the greatest date is in the first record, once it is retrieved and the value assigned to the variable, a `goto` jump to a label is executed to skip the rest of the records.

To see it clear, this is the same code, more readable, but separated in steps and using a temporary file

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"

    (   for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=,/" %%a in (data.csv) do (
            set /a "x=%%c*10000+%%a*100+%%b"
            echo(!x:~0,4!/!x:~4,2!/!x:~-2!
        )
    )> "%tempFile%"  

    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in (
        ' type "%tempFile%" ^| sort /r '
    ) do set "last_date=%%b/%%c/%%a" & goto done

:done
    echo %last_date%

    del /f /q "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal
```

The inner loop in original code is now the first loop. File is readed by the `for`, date elements extracted (see tokens and delims), date normalized (`set /a` arithmetics) and the list saved to a temporary file

The outter loop in original code is the second one here. The file is readed with a `type` command, the data piped to `sort /r` and the resulting lines are tokenized by the `for` command to reformat the date.

**Edited** to adapt to comments

Aacini is right, his code is faster, but given that i just started this way, .... Anyway, the changes in this code can be translated to his solution

This should handle differences in date fields (aditional spaces and aditional initial 0) and missing fields.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (
       'cmd /q /v:on /c "for /f "delims^=" %%z in (data.csv) do for /f "tokens^=1-3 delims^=^," %%w in (" %%~z ") do if not "%%~y" equ "" for /f "tokens^=1-3 delims^=/ " %%a in ("%%~x") do (set /a "x^=%%c*10000 + 100%%a %% 100*100 +  100%%b %% 100" >nul & echo(^!x^!:%%~x)" ^| sort /r '
    ) do set "latest_date=%%a" & goto done
:done
echo %latest_date%
```

The inner `for` loops :

- `for %%z` will read lines from file
- `for %%w` will tokenize the readed line with an aditional space at the start and end of the line to prevent problems with adjacent delimiters removal.
- `for %%a` handles the date normalization and outputs the calculated value used for sort and the readed date.

The outer `for %%a` loop will split the retrieved record to separate the calculated value from the readed date.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
However, what I get from database is not standard format, sometime M/D/YYYY, sometime MM/D/YYYY ,sometime M/DD/YYYY and sometime MM/DD/YYYY. Um... So what should I do?

Comment: @Question-erXDD, i have added an adapted code sample at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This simpler method should run faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set latest_num=0
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=,/" %%a in (theFile.csv) do (
   set /A "new_num=((%%c*100)+%%a)*100+%%b"
   if !new_num! gtr !latest_num! (
      set latest_num=!new_num!
      set latest_date=%%a/%%b/%%c
   )
)
echo Latest date: %latest_date%
```

Comment: +1 :O I did the calc but didn't see it. The pipe solution was my first idea and didn't think more. One more lesson learned.

Comment: Ops Thanks for your info. However, if sometime I have the NULL value (e.g. a,,) in the middle of the database, what should I do?

Comment: You should post a segment of the file that include the bad part; otherwise, how we could have an idea of what the problem is? Edit your question, DON'T post data in a comment, but post a comment here as an advice after your edition.

Answer (score 1):

In the CMD the variable are displayes in alphabetical order and from the smaller to the bigger value.

So we transform all your dates in variables like this : `set #142707=7/27/2014`

Then looping against a `set #` we take the last value who is the latest date.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (data.csv) do call:checkDate %%a
for /f  "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set #') do set $LatestDate=%%a
echo The Latest Date : [!$LatestDate!]
exit/b

:CheckDate
set $out=
set "$Date=%1"
set "$Date=%$Date:/= %
for %%b in (%$Date%) do (
    set $val=0%%b
    set $out=!$val:~-2!!$out!)
set #!$out!=%1
```

Comment: Thz for yr info. I got some problem. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/7vMBM.jpg) Why I cannot read the file ?

Comment: Try : `for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('type "c:\b.txt"') do echo %%x`